# Would codes after try and except be executed?

Tags: python, exception

Let's say a code like this

```
try:
    objectToBeUsed = func1()
except:
    objectToBeUsed = false

nextValue = func2(objectToBeUsed)
```

Would the last line be executed, whether exception is caught or not? Do I need to use `finally` here?

Comment: Um...that depends on the result of your call to `func2` with whatever is passed in on either `try` or `except`.  But `nextValue` will have *some* value.  I can't infer what from the context.

Comment: @Makoto I guess my question was not clear. I am wondering if that whole line will be executed or not.

Comment: *Would the last line be executed, whether exception is caught or not?* yes. *Do I need to use finally here?* no

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself? I think that's the easiest way to get the answer.

Comment: @Christian my code seems to work, but I am not sure since I am running plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finally` is usually used to execute clean up code, whether an exception has been raised or not. If I understand correctly, calling `func2()` is part of your normal program flow and is not considered clean up. So you should not use `finally` in this case.

Read more about python exception handling here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be executed.

However, that's probably exactly why it's a bad idea to use  a bare `except` with no specificed exception classes to catch.  It's rare that you want to keep blithely going along in the case of *any* exception.  The exception could be a KeyboardInterrupt, for instance.

You catch the specific exceptions that indicate situations where you actually do want to set `objectToBeUsed = False`, and let other exceptions propagate up if you can't handle them.